libvlc folder not installed when using ClickOnce Publishing
I have a WinForms .NET 4.8 Visual Studio ClickOnce (Platform=Any CPU) application that uses VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows and LibVLCSharp.Winforms NuGet packages.
After updating to the latest versions (3.0.20 and 3.8.5) of these libraries from NuGet, I found that the libvlc directory (and contents) are not installed on the client PC. The libvlc directory and contents are published to the server by Visual Studio during the Build/Publish process. Upon installation on the client PC, the libvlc directory is not copied from the server to the client PC. Previously, it was copied to the client PC. I have updated VLC versions periodically for the last couple of years without problem.
Before updating, the NuGet versions were 3.0.18 and 3.7.0.
The published ClickOnce xxxxx.exe.mainfest includes the libvlc folder files when using the old version of the VLC NuGet packages but not when using the current version of VLC NuGet packages.

nothing seems to have changed in the libvlc packaging side so this is weird https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-nuget you could do a diagnostic build and see if something is skipped for some reason..

I enabled Diagnostic logging which yielded more than 8K lines. I saw in the log that the libvlc directory files were known to the build/publish process but could not see any obvious message that told me why the libvlc directory files were not published to the client when installed from the server.
I decided to try reading the LIBVLC NuGet-related documentation to see if there was anything that would give me an idea for a solution. I found this page: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-nuget/-/blob/master/library-copy-enabling.md and decided to modify my Visual Studio project file.
To
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">

and
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">

I added:
<VlcWindowsX64Enabled>true</VlcWindowsX64Enabled>
<VlcWindowsX86Enabled>true</VlcWindowsX86Enabled>

Doing that solved the problem. I have no idea why it worked for several years without those parameters but consider the issue solved.
